# VBS to return part of a command line return with RegEx

Tags: regex, shell, vbscript, command

I'm trying to execute a command via ssh, take only the first part of the returned command, and set it as a variable to be used.  I'm attempting to use RegExp and because I only need the first 4 digits, I use the pattern code "^\d{1,4}"  I can successfully get the entire return via this code;

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set oExec = WshShell.Exec ("ssh -un -pw command")
      Do Until oExec.StdOut.AtEndOfStream
         ID = oExec.StdOut.ReadLine
      Loop
       WScript.Echo ID
```

But Now when I try to use RegExp and echo to see if I'm getting what I want I get a "Type Mismatch" error

```
Set RegExp = New RegExp
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set oExec = WshShell.Exec ("ssh -un -pw command")
RegExp.Pattern = "^\d{1,4}"
      Do Until oExec.StdOut.AtEndOfStream
         ID = oExec.StdOut.ReadLine
          WScript.Echo RegExp.execute(ID)
      Loop
```

If anyone has any incite on what's wrong with the code please let me know.  If you know of any alternative I'd appreciate it.  Using a shell script I can get what I'm looking for but I need to run this VBS with windows.  Here's the Shell script if anyone can translate it to VBS.

```
.............for i in `command | sed ‘1d’ | awk ‘{print $1}’`..............
```

Appreciate any help in advance...  Been racking my brain on this one for a while and getting burnt out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't .Echo an object like the match collection you get from .Execute; access the .Value of its first item:

```
>> sInp = "1234xxx"
>> Set reHead = New RegExp
>> reHead.Pattern = "^\d{4}"
>> Set oMTS = reHead.Execute(sInp)
>> WScript.Echo oMTS(0).Value
>>
1234
>> WScript.Echo oMTS
>>
Error Number:       13
Error Description:  Type mismatch
```

Comment: Oooooooooooooooooh that explains it...  That's exactly what I needed Ekkeheard!!!  I'm now able to parse the first group of numbers and set it as a variable with .Value...  Thanks!!!!